# Program to check if a given number is present in an array having all numbers in ascending order

Tags: c, arrays, function

The following C program works fine but not for the values which are at zeroeth position or smaller than the value at zeroeth position. This program basically takes a value and checks if the given value is in the array or not.It first compares the given value with the middle value of the array and determines if it matches it or is in the upper half or lower half and then proceeds into the selected half and proceeds in a similar way there as well until it gets the value or if the range comes out to be zero. But here it shows no result just a blinking cursor on screen(in case of value at zeroeth position or a value smaller than that).

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n, x,b;
    int s[]= {2,3,7,9,33,58};
    n=6;
    printf("Enter the number which we want to find in the array ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    b=binsearch(n, s, x);
    printf("The position is: %d",b);
}
int binsearch(int n, int v[], int x)
{
    int low, high, mid;
    low=0;
    high= n-1;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if (x<v[mid])
            high=mid+1;
        else if (x>v[mid])
            low=mid+1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If we make following changes then the program gives the same problem but for value at last position or larger.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n, x,b;
    int s[]= {2,3,7,9,33,58};
    n=6;
    printf("Enter the number which we want to find in the array ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    b=binsearch(n, s, x);
    printf("The position is: %d",b);
}
int binsearch(int n, int v[], int x)
{
    int low, high, mid;
    low=0;
    high= n-1;
    while(low<high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if (x<v[mid])
            high=mid;
        else if (x>v[mid])
            low=mid;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What's a position smaller than zero?

Comment: Not for position smaller than zero but for value lesser than the value which is at zero position

Comment: In your first program use high=mid-1.

Comment: jeevan_23 Thanks Sir I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to modify your binary search function to take `low` and `high` as parameters instead of `n`.

```
int binsearch(int v[], int low, int high, int x)
{
    int mid=(low+high)/2;
    if(low<=high)
    {
        if (x<v[mid])
            high=mid-1;
        else if (x>v[mid])
            low=mid+1;
        else
            return mid;
        return binsearch(v, low, high, x);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If `x` is equal to `v[mid]`, `mid` is returned.

If `x` is lower than the middle value, `high` is made `mid-1` and if `x` is higher than the middle value, `low` is made `mid+1` thereby leaving one half of the part of array currenlty under consideration.

`binsearch()` is a recursive function which keep getting called till `low>high`.

The function would return the position if a match is found and otherwise `-1` is returned.

Comment: Sir what is the line       return binsearch(v, low, high, x)       doing here?

Comment: Is it to make this function recursive? But what is a recursive function exactly

Comment: @ChadhaNikhlesh The function is calling itself. It's a recursive function. If `v[mid]` is `x`, `mid` is returned. Otherwise, `low` and `high` values are readjutsted (ie, the part of array to be searched is changed. Halved, actually) and the function is called again with the new values of `low` and `high`.

Comment: @ChadhaNikhlesh A [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) is a function which calls itself.